# Can't even get the basics of Angular Material running -- tried following material.angular.io but more confused now

Tags: angular, angular-material

My starting point was wanting a pony -- or in this case a datepicker. But I can't seem to install Material and get it running. Is it required that most Angular instruction be obtuse?

I've `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`

But in app.module ts, 
`MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule`
Show as "Class _____ is not an Angular module." So what do I do with that??

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';  

 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule
],
  providers: [
  MatDatepickerModule
],
```

Comment: why did you import `MatNativeDateModule` ?

Comment: Also, delete it the module from the providers array `providers: [MatDatepickerModule],`

Comment: @NadhirFalta from another commentary on it; thtat's why I'm so confused

Comment: Errror: <input [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker> Can't bind to 'matDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: Did you re-run your npm start again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.module.ts, I added

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
```

in imports: [] I added MaDatepickermodule, ditto exports: []

Now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Embrace the Angular Schematics paradigm, and do not install/update Angular and NgLibs via `npm` but via `ng add/update`. You will keep your hair in place and your project running ;)